# grep to find words with unique letters

Tags: grep

how to use grep to find occurrences of words from a dictionary file which have a given set of letters with the restriction that each letter occurs once and only once.

EG if the letters are abc then the expected output is:

cab

---

EDIT:

Given a dictionary file (that is a file containing one word per line such as `/usr/share/dict/words` on mac os x operating system) and a set of (unique) characters, I want to print out all of the dictionary file's words that contain each character of the input set once and only once. For example if the set of characters is `{a,b,c}` then print out all (3-letter) words that contain each character of the set.

I am looking, preferably, for a solution that uses just grep expressions.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: bash script or just command line. Mac os x computer.

Answer (score 1):

Given a series of letters, for example `abc`, you can convert each one to a lookahead, like this:

```
^(?=[^a]*a[^a]*)(?=[^b]*b[^b]*)(?=[^c]*c[^c]*)$
```

You may need to use the "extended regex" flag `-E` to use this regex with `grep`.

---

To create this regex from a string, you could use `sed` (an exercise for the reader)

Comment: thanks, that looks promising. However, when I use that expression in either grep -E or egrep command line I get an error message: "repetition-operator operand invalid". Sample command line is: grep - E 'your expression' filename

Comment: Are you putting the regex within quotes? Ie `grep -E 'above-regex'`?

Comment: yes - it appears that the mac os x implementation of grep -E or egrep doesn't include this lookahead feature. When I do a very simple example: egrep 'a(?=b)' filename it fails with the same error message.

Comment: I added a comment below with a solution I found. For the letters a,b,c the solution is: `grep '^[abc]\{3\}$' /usr/share/dict/words | grep a | grep b | grep c`

Comment: that solution matches *any number* of each letter, not *exactly one* of each letter as your question asks: *"each letter occurs once and only once"*. You should change your regex from simply `a` to `^[^a]*a[^a]*$`. Also, if you find an answer yourself, you should answer your own question (by posting an "answer") and accept it (it's perfectly OK to do that)

Comment: I think my solution does satisfy once and only once. In given example, I am looking for 3-letter words that contain each of `{a,b,c}` once and only once. The first `grep` extracts all 3-letter words that contain only a,b,c.  The single letter `greps` then insure that a word contains at least one each of `{a,b,c}` and since there's only 3 letters in the word, cannot contain anything else. Same for general n-letter case. (I guess it might not have been completely clear that I am looking for n-letter words only.) Anyway, thanks for your comments and I will post my solution as an answer.

Comment: I didn't notice you were inputting only 3-letter words, which is a degenerate case. There are only 6 possible combinations, do you could use a regex OR on the literals.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -E ^[abc]{3}.$ <Dictionary file> | grep -v -e a.*a -e b.*b -e c.*c
```

i.e. Find all three letter strings matching the input and pipe these through inverse grep to remove strings with double letters.

I'm using the '.' after {3} because my dictionary file is windows based so has an extra carriage return or line feed. So, that's probably not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a Perl solution.  Note, you'll need to add more words to the dictionary, and read input in to the `$input` variable.  An array of valid words will end up in `@results`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Data::Dumper;

my $input = "abc";

my @dictionary = qw(aaa aac aad aal aam aap aar aas aat aaw aba abc abd abf abg
  abh abm abn abo abr abs abv abw aca acc ace aci ack acl acp acs act acv ada adb
  adc add adf adh adl adn ado adp adq adr ads adt adw aea aeb aec aed aef aes aev
  afb afc afe aff afg afi afk afl afn afp aft afu afv agb agc agl agm agn ago agp
  ...

  PUT A REAL DICTIONARY HERE!

  ...
  zie zif zig zii zij zik zil zim zin zio zip zir zis zit ziu ziv zlm zlo zlx zma
  zme zmi zmu zna zoa zob zoe zog zoi zol zom zon zoo zor zos zot zou zov zoy zrn
  zsr zub zud zug zui zuk zul zum zun zuo zur zus zut zuz zva zwo zye zzz);

# Generate a lookahead expression for each character in the input word
my $regexp = join("", map { "(?=.*$_)" } split(//, $input));

my @results;
foreach my $word (@dictionary) {

  # If the size of the input doesn't match the dictionary word, skip to the
  # next word.
  if (length($input) != length($word)) {
    next;
  }

  if ($word =~ /$regexp/) {
    push(@results, $word);
  }
}

print Dumper @results;
```

Comment: thanks; I have shell scripts also that work but I was hoping to find a solution using some form of grep. Eg \{[abc]\} defines a pattern for all first letters and you can reference \1 to make the second letter the same as the first; so it would be nice to be able to use something like [^\1] to make the second letter different from the first but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Perl can often be reduced to `awk`, `sed`, `grep`, and friends.  Post your solution, and ask how to port it to another language.

Comment: I was able to find a solution; for a given set of letters it uses just grep. For example, for the letters a,b,c the solution would be: `grep '^[abc]\{3\}$' /usr/share/dict/words | grep a | grep b | grep c`  A simple bash script can be run for the more general case, passing the letters as $1.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found involves using `grep` first to extract all n-letter words that contain only letters from the input set - although some letters might appear more than once, some may not appear; (again I am assuming that the input letters are unique). Then it does a series of 1-letter `greps` to make sure each letter occurs at least once. Because the words are of length n this ensures the word contains each letter once and only once. For example, if the input character set is `(a,b,c}` then the solution would be:

`grep -E '^[abc]{3}$' /usr/share/dict/words | grep a | grep b | grep c`

a simple bash script can be written which creates this `grep` string and executes it against the word file, using $1 as the input letter set. It might not be the most efficient method of generating the string, but as I am not familiar with `sed` or `awk` it does seem to solve my problem. The script I created is:

```
#!/bin/sh
slen=${#1}
g2="'^[$1]{$slen}\$'"
g3=""
ix1=0
while [ $ix1 -lt $slen ]
do
  g3="$g3 | grep ${1:$ix1:1}"
  ix1=$((ix1+1))
done
eval grep -E $g2 /usr/share/dict/words $g3
```